# How to stop button from moving

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a button that, when pressed, is supposed to expand the element behind it (`.nav` which contains `.work` and `.contact`) out in both directions. However, I can't seem to keep the button in the center.

```js
$(function() {
  var nav = $('.nav');
  var button = $('.nav button');
  button.on('click', function(){
    nav.toggleClass('active');
    if(nav.hasClass('active'))
      button.text('');
    else
      button.text('');
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.nav {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 330px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.nav.active {
  width: 1000px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.navigation button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  Height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #2e0513!important;
  background: url(TransplantAltFontbackgroundvector.png) 12px 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 325px 325px;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation.active button {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation:hover button {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
  transform: scale(1.01);
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation.active:hover button {
  box-shadow: none!important;
  transform: scale(1.1)!important;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation button img {
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
.work,
.contact {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.work a {
  font-family: arapey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.contact a {
  font-family: arapey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav.active > .work {
  visibility: visible!important;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 125px;
  top: 150px;
}
.nav.active > .contact {
  visibility: visible!important;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 125px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="nav">
    <button>
    </button>
    <div class="work">
      <A HREF="#work">work</A>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <A HREF="#contact">contact</A>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the nav a style of `position: relative`. Then, toggle a class (or just add the styling, should work as well) to the button on click that does the following:

```
button.my-pressed-class {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This should keep it in the middle.

Edit: Keep in mind you already have a transform set on the button on hover. Just, add the translateX to hover when the button has the aforementioned class, to avoid it from moving around on hover.

Answer (score 0):

add postion relative to .navigation and position absolute to .nav with left value

```js
$(function() {
  var nav = $('.nav');
  var button = $('.nav button');
  button.on('click', function(){
    nav.toggleClass('active');
    if(nav.hasClass('active'))
      button.text('');
    else
      button.text('');
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.navigation {
   position: relative;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 330px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
.nav.active {
  width: 1000px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.navigation button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  Height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #2e0513!important;
  background: url(TransplantAltFontbackgroundvector.png) 12px 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 325px 325px;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation.active button {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation:hover button {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
  transform: scale(1.01);
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation.active:hover button {
  box-shadow: none!important;
  transform: scale(1.1)!important;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation button img {
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
.work,
.contact {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.work a {
  font-family: arapey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.contact a {
  font-family: arapey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav.active > .work {
  visibility: visible!important;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 125px;
  top: 150px;
}
.nav.active > .contact {
  visibility: visible!important;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 125px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="nav">
    <button>
    </button>
    <div class="work">
      <A HREF="#work">work</A>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <A HREF="#contact">contact</A>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```